# Is there a way to have USB data transferred from Pi to HAT?

Tags: gpio, usb, hat, design

I'm designing a Raspberry Pi HAT that requires USB for debugging. The 40-pin GPIO connector that connects the Pi to the HAT doesn't seem to have any USB designated pins. I would like to use the USB port already located on the Pi to do the debugging but I don't know if that is possible. Would I need to include a USB port on the HAT itself or is it possible to use the USB port already located on the Pi?

[image: Raspberry Pi GPIO]

Comment: The port on the Pi is hard wired to the BCM processor, there is no way to hijack any of the physical port for hat use without extensive PCB mods. Certainly one can conceive of a way to forward debug data to the hat over GPIO or UART or what have you through the PI . But that isn't what you need if you have a device with a USB debug built in

Answer (score 2):

The USB port is NOT available on the 40-ping connector!

If a USB serial is enought for debugging then you could add a USB-Serial chip like CP210x, CH340/CH341 or equal to the UART RX/TX pins, then you will get a USB serial on your HAT.